# Can "encoding" and "binary" be both used for `Text::CSV::Encoded`?

Tags: perl, csv

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV::Encoded;

my $csv = Text::CSV::Encoded->new({
    encoding => "utf8",
    binary => 1,
  });

while (my $row = $csv->getline (*STDIN)) {
  my @fields = @$row;
  print join('|', @fields), "\n";
}
```

I use the above Perl code to parse the following CSV file.

```
a,"1
2
3"
```

I get the following error.

```
$ ./main.pl < main.csv 
Use of uninitialized value $encoding in pattern match (m//) at /Users/xxx/Library/ActivePerl-5.16/lib/Text/CSV/Encoded/Coder/Encode.pm line 44, <STDIN> line 3.
a|1
2
3
```

Can "encoding" and "binary" be both used for `Text::CSV::Encoded`?

Answer (score 2):

You want `encoding_in` (required when parsing; used to decode inputs) instead of `encoding` (used to encode strings passed to Perl, something that should never be needed).

```
my $csv = Text::CSV::Encoded->new({
   encoding_in => "utf-8",
   binary => 1,
});
```